# AVFoundation AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate called multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, streaming, avfoundation, avplayer

I have implemented an instance of the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol. 
However I do not understand why the method - `resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:` is being called multiple times almost immediately with the same type of request.

What I do in the implementation is to see if an http request for this `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest` is already running. If yes, then it cancels the previous request and starts a new http request for the associated media corresponding to this `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest`.

The problem is that this causes my `AVAsset` to load slowly because multiple http requests are being started and then stopped to respond to the last `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest`. And if I do not respond to the last `AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest` but only the first, then the asset doesn't load at all.

Can you give me some tips or suggestions on how to deal with this?

Thank you.

Comment: It appears that on iOS 10.x, [resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:] will be called multiple times (up-to 1 minute with 5 seconds apart) to get the FairPlay license data. If you try the same code on iOS 9.x, you will see that there is only one call.

I'd like to make AVPlayer fail as soon as first FP license request fails however I do not have a solution for iOS 10.x either.

Comment: I testing on ios 9.3 it fire multiple time.

Comment: Confirmed on iOS it can fire multiple times as well. Caused a bit of an issue when errordelegates are called down the line multiple times for me.